# Iphone App Installation Error

Tags: iphone

I am trying to install an application on my iphone for testing.  I have installed projects on the phone before.  The project compiles and links fine, but when xCode tries to install my app on the phone I get the error:

**Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xE800003A)**

0xE800003A, at '/SourceCache/iPhoneXcodePlugin/iPhoneXcodePlugin-132/XCRemoteIPhone_MobileDeviceIO.m:722'

When observing the dialog at the bottom of xCode, it says "installing test*.app on yourIphone"

This name is different than the name at the end of my bundle identifier.
It must be a build setting I can't find.  Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your phone is provisioned to work with your app and that you have the proper provisioning file installed on your phone. Finally, you might try restarting your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Hit this site first 
http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/

If that doesn't fix your problem go to the Developer Portal on Apple's site.

You have something out of sync that is causing your iPhone to not, for lack of a better term, trust that you have permission to put an app on your phone. You have to make sure you have your build environment set up correctly and make sure all your code signing credentials are set up correctly. The link provided above or the Dev Portal will assist you through that.